# freeing std::list member

Tags: c++, stl, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have a list defined as such `std::list<BunnyInfo> bList;`, private, inside a class where `BunnyInfo` is a structure

```
struct BunnyList::BunnyInfo {
    std::string name;
    char gender;
    std::string color;
    unsigned int age : 6; // 0 - 63
    bool mutant;
};
```

where the list grows via member function

```
void BunnyList::add(int count){
    bListIter iter;
    while(count--){
        BunnyInfo *bNew = &fill(*new BunnyInfo());
        for(iter = bList.begin(); iter != bList.end(); iter++){
            if(iter->age <= bNew->age)
                break;
        }
        bList.insert(iter, *bNew);
    }
}
```

where `fill()` is just a function that generates values for the structure. I also have a member function that deletes half the list

```
void BunnyList::reap(){
    int toKill = bList.size() / 2;
    int find;
    bListIter iter;
    while(toKill--){
        find = rng(0, bList.size()-1);
        iter = bList.begin();
        for(int i = 0; i < find; i++)   // traverse list to the find-th node;
            iter++;
        delete &(*iter);
        bList.erase(iter);
    }
}
```

My question is, how would I delete the list member and at the same time free the resources allocated via `add()`. `delete &(*iter);` produces an error, I think, since without it the program runs okay. But simply calling `erase()` doesn't free the `BunnyInfo` associated with the list node.

I'm new to using the STL.

Comment: You probably want to avoid `std::list` unless you have a very specific reason to use it. (`std::vector` is superior in almost every way)

Comment: Why is your add function allocating a dynamic BunnyInfo, instead of just creating one locally?

Comment: Well the list is sorted via `age` as the list grows; I do in-the-middle insertions a lot so I figure a vector would be less ideal.(?)

Comment: @BenjaminLindley what do you mean?

Comment: @lightburst: I mean, why are allocating a `BunnyInfo` object on the heap with `new`, then adding that object to the list via a dereferenced pointer?  Rather than just creating a `BunnyInfo` object locally, like this: `BunnyInfo bNew;` -- Then fiddling with that object and adding it to the list, like this: `blist.insert(iter,bNew);` -- If you did that, then you wouldn't have your problem with de-allocating the object in the `reap` function.

Comment: OHH okay. I figure I would be the one to allocate space for the list as it grows.

Comment: @lightburst: In fact, the object you create is not even the one that gets added to the list.  Because this: `bList.insert(iter, *bNew);` -- creates a copy of the object pointed to by `bNew` and stores that object in the list.  So actually, when you call `erase`, the list will deallocate the object.  However, you've already leaked the original objects.

Comment: If you want to sort by age as the list grows, consider using the STL priority queue data structure and/or STL algorithms' `make_heap`, `push_heap`, and `pop_heap` functions.

Comment: @lightburst: insertions in a linked list are only constant-time if you already have a pointer/iterator to the place where you want to insert. If you're searching for an insertion point you're very likely better off with a `vector`.

Answer (score 5):

Since the list is declared `std::list<BunnyInfo>`, its `insert` makes a copy of the object being inserted, and `erase` automatically disposes of the copy.  You thus need not and cannot use `delete` on that copy.

Since your `add` alloctes with `new` an object which it does not `delete` (and does not store in any data structure), there is a memory leak in `add`.

If you want to store pointers in the list, you need to declare the list as `std::list<BunnyInfo *>`.